# Can I set up PYTHONPATH for Lambda Function of Cloud9?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloud9

I created 2 Lambda Functions from AWS Resources menu in Cloud9.

I wanna have common modules for these Functions.

I made New Folder for the common modules and add the path `~/environment/python/lib` to PYTHONPATH of Preferences -> Python Support.

I did `Run` main function with `Lambda(local)`.

But I got `Unable to import module 'main/lambda_function': No module named 'common'`.

Can I set up PYTHONPATH for Lambda Function in Cloud9?

Or is there a　better practice for having common modules for several Lambda Functions?

My folder tree:

```
root
|-python
  |-lib     <- for uploading to Lambda Layers
    common.py
|-app
  |-main
    |-lambda_function.py
  |-main2
    |-lambda_function.py
```

my lambda_function.py:

```
import common
```

Comment: Common modules should be placed in a layer and multiple functions should use that same layer.

Comment: yes, but layers don't seem refered in Cloud9. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976291/aws-cloud9-referencing-lambda-layer-locally

Answer (score 0):

Just output the `PYTHONPATH` in your python file before you do anything else:

```
import os
print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])

import ...

def lambda_handler(event,context):
  ...
```

You will see as part of the Function Logs that it outputs the environment variable as `/var/runtime`. Even if you set that path through the Cloud9 settings, you will discover just as I did that those settings do not hold.

I was hoping to setup all my layers under `~/environment/layers/layername`, so I would have for example all my libraries and dependencies for scikit-learn under: `~/environment/layers/scikit-learn/python/...` and I would use that same scikit-learn directory to actually create my layer with for deployment remotely.

But that did not work.